# Where Clause for Multiple Filters for the Same Field Plus a "SELECT ALL" Option

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched Stack Overflow and other sites extensively, and I can't quite find the answer to my question. It's a complex problem, and most solutions I've found fall short.

I'm using Logi Info Studio to display a custom data table for a client. All that really matters about this is that I'm dealing with 3 dropdowns, each of which has a "All x" option. When one of these is clicked, a SQL statement should be executed to filter the data table.

I have one table in the database. It has columns for business type and data type. For example:

```
BUSINESS_TYPE        DATA_TYPE
Bob's Store          direct
Thrifty Mart         direct
Mike's Car Repair    indirect
Quick Lube           indirect
Physician's Assoc    other
Jewelry Wholesalers  other
```

I have the dropdowns set to display all of the unique BUSINESS_TYPE values for each data type, and each dropdown has an option for "All", like "All Direct". Logi will pass in the options the user selects in the dropdowns as tokens, like @Request.Direct, @Request.Indirect, and @Request.Other. From here, I need to take the token values and filter the data accordingly (Logi handles the tokens fine.)

Where I run into problems is I'm using 3 different arguments to filter in my WHERE clause, and each of these could be an "All" option, which will be passed in literally as 'All Direct', for instance.

Here is my query. It's designed to make a sort of crosstab, adding up transactions paid on time and total transactions for each country.

```
Select COUNTRY,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'Indirect' AND ON_TIME_INDICATOR = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'IndirectOnTime',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'Direct' AND ON_TIME_INDICATOR = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DirectOnTime',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'Other' AND ON_TIME_INDICATOR = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OtherOnTime',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'Indirect' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'IndirectTotal',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'Direct' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DirectTotal',
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OtherTotal',
  COUNT(*) AS 'Country_Total'
From TRANSACTIONS
WHERE

GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

I need the user to be able to select a value from each of the dropdowns or the "All" options in pretty much any combination. After a selection is made, say, an indirect BUSINESS_TYPE for the indirect dropdown and "All"' for the other 2, I need it to filter just the BUSINESS_TYPE records that are indirect by the value selected, but not the direct or other records. If the user selects the "All" option for all 3 dropdowns, I need to display all records for the BUSINESS_TYPE field, which is complicated by the 'All Direct', 'All Indirect', and 'All Other' values that Logi will pass to the query.

Yes, my WHERE clause is empty, because I just don't know what to do to accomplish this anymore. I've tried various combos of AND and OR statements. I've tried using COUNT on the BUSINESS_TYPE field with a HAVING statement. I've tinkered with subqueries, but I honestly don't know how this would improve things. I've tried using NULLIF() to somehow deactivate a parameter if it's "All".

From what I can tell, a stored proc would work fine here, so I can certainly do that. I'm not committed to just using a regular SQL statement like this.

I hope I've explained this well. It's complicated, and I'm afraid I'm getting bogged down in it and having trouble seeing the forest for the trees.
Sorry for anything I left out, etc. I'll be happy to provide whatever additional info may be needed. I can go into deeper detail.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Stored procedure is by far the easier route.

Comment: Are the 3 parameters mutually exclusive?

Comment: This is actually not as difficult as you're making it. This is known as a catch-all query and they are incredibly common, especially when searching. See this article for a number of ways to not only write this, but more importantly keep it fast. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
where
    (DATA_TYPE='Direct' and (@Request.Direct in ('All Direct', BUSINESS_TYPE)) or
    (DATA_TYPE='Indirect' and (@Request.Indirect in ('All Indirect', BUSINESS_TYPE)) or
    (DATA_TYPE='Other' and (@Request.Other in ('All Other', BUSINESS_TYPE))
```

Comment: I think this did it! I wouldn't have thought to put the syntax like that. SQL never ceases to amaze me. I've run through the various combos that could be selected by the user, and the filtering seems to be spot-on so far. Thanks!